# How to convert a difference in timestamp to miliseconds?

Tags: python, datetime, time, timedelta

I have two dates in timestamp and their difference is

```
dt
0.006951093673706055
```

dt is: `(1669983551.287477-1669983551.280526)`

I want to generate several dates (in datetime) with that difference

Now normally I would do

```
date_list = [datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=x) for x in range(n)]
```

but here timedelta uses the number of milliseconds.

So my question is how can I get the timestamp dt `0.006951093673706055` to miliseconds?

Comment: Seconds to milliseconds is just a factor of 1000, so something like `int(dt * 1e3)` should do the trick, if the unit of your duration `dt` is seconds (float).

Comment: Is  "timestamp" expressed in seconds? (this `dt` was obtained with the function `timestamp`

Comment: Yes, that returns seconds since the Unix epoch. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A time in milliseconds is the time in seconds multiplied by 1000

```py
dt = (1669983551.287477-1669983551.280526) # 0.006951 sec
dt_millisec = dt * 1000                    # 6.951 millisec
```

Comment: So `timestamps` is expressed in seconds? I didn't think about that thanks!

Comment: This will fail drastically around leap seconds and NTP clock steps; due to NTP adjustments, it will be also be slightly inaccurate.  What is needed is a precise (vs accurate) clock (e.g. monotonic), possibly with a fudge factor if needed (depending on the accuracy of the precise clock).